# Como aplican los editores de imagenes los filtros?

Tags: javascript, imagen

estoy desarrollando un editor de imagenes simple en JavaScript, y hasta ahora todo iba bien, puedo aplicar diferentes filtros a la imagen(temperatura, Blanco y negro, brillo, contraste, etc.)

el problema radica en que cuando aplico varios filtros, por ejemplo, si aplico **Temperatura** junto a **Brillo** y luego aplico **Blanco y negro** el ultimo parece no ser en blanco y negro sino que niega los otros colores, mi pregunta es si deberia aplicar el filtro sobre el anterior o sobre la imagen base

actualmente estoy aplicando cada filtro a la imagen base, luego para convinar todo solo sumo los filtros y resto la base

*base.data* es un Array de  tipo **byte[]** que conforma la imagen
ejemplo:

```
Blender.register('normal', function (i, blend, layer, base) {
  blend.data[i] += (layer.data[i] - base.data[i]);
  blend.data[i + 1] += (layer.data[i + 1] - base.data[i + 1]);
  blend.data[i + 2] += (layer.data[i + 2] - base.data[i + 2]);

  blend.data[i] = Math.clamp(blend.data[i], 0, 255);
  blend.data[i + 1] = Math.clamp(blend.data[i + 1], 0, 255);
  blend.data[i + 2] = Math.clamp(blend.data[i + 2], 0, 255);


  return blend;
});
```

no se si debo sumar los filtros o como puedo aplicarlos?

gracias de antemano!!